# Collapsing Navbar when the width of the window resizes [Bootstrap 5]

Tags: javascript, navbar, width, bootstrap-5

So I was trying to figure out how to add some type of eventListener to trigger Collapse class on Navbar in bootstrap when `window.matchMedia('min-width: 1400px');`

I was looking for the code responsible for triggering the class and I came to this:

```
EventHandler.on(document, EVENT_CLICK_DATA_API$4, SELECTOR_DATA_TOGGLE$4, function (event) {
// preventDefault only for \<a\> elements (which change the URL) not inside the collapsible element
if (event.target.tagName === 'A' || event.delegateTarget && event.delegateTarget.tagName === 'A') {
event.preventDefault();
}
for (const element of SelectorEngine.getMultipleElementsFromSelector(this)) {
Collapse.getOrCreateInstance(element, {
toggle: false
}).toggle();
}
});
```

The EVENT_CLICK_DATA_API$4 is 'click' trigger and SELECTOR_DATA_TOGGLE$4 is the target which the 'click' will trigger the collapse. Function (event) is responsible for creating the instance of the class. Can I somehow use this knowledge to add window resize as EVENT_CLICK_DATA_API$4? The problem is that EventHandler.on is constructed the way that EVENT_CLICK_DATA_API$4, SELECTOR_DATA_TOGGLE$4 must be strings.

If you recommend easier approach it would be very much appreciated!